# React Native Nested Navigation GO_BACK handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

I created a nested navigation in my app. There is a TabNavigator as default in NavigationContainer and it contains screens and HomeFeed Stack Navigator which is like this;

- BottomTabBar

  - HomeStackNavigator (HomeFeed)

    - Detail Screen
    - Settings Screen
  - Content Screen

When ever I go to Detail screen from Content screen I cannot come back to Content screen from Detail. It appears an error `The action 'GO_BACK' was not handled by any navigator.`

Can someone help me please?

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",

"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
```

Comment: I think you should up your code to https://expo.dev/

Comment: @zuet thanks I fixed that by adding `backBehavior="history"` to my TabNavigator. 